# How can I return back to point position after jumping by `<down-mouse-1>`?

Tags: mouse, navigation, mark-ring

How can I return back to point position after jumping by `<down-mouse-1>`?

Example: moving in the buffer for a while with `C-pbfn`, then use mouse for navigation, and press `C-u C-<space>` trying to return back, but last point not in `mark-ring`.

Comment: By `C-pbfn` I mean navigation via keyboard. And by `<down-mouse-1>` – mouse clicking. So when I reposition cursor by mouse, I want to be able to jump back where it was by `C-u C-<space>`, how I usually do while navigating via keyboard. Thank you.

Comment: You mean clicking `mouse-1`, I guess. That does not set the mark. Are you asking how to make it set the mark? If so, that's easy to do, but if you use the mouse at all besides just clicking `mouse-1` then that will interfere with what it normally does. Normally, `mouse-1` sets point, not the mark. That lets you drag the mouse to select text or use `mouse-3` to select text or double- or triple-click `mouse-1` to select text. Better be sure of what you want first. ;-) Have you tried clicking `mouse-1` followed by immediately clicking `mouse-3`? Does have the effect you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, put mark (without activating region, unless it activated explicitly) AND THAN set the new point. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```el
(defun my-mouse-1 (event)
  "..."
  (interactive "e")
  (mouse-set-point event)
  (push-mark))

(global-set-key (kbd "<mouse-1>") 'my-mouse-1)
```

(Not that I really recommend doing this.  You won't be able to take advantage of double and triple clicking `mouse-1`.)